# How do I display different text than the cell text in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet where I have two cells on one side, one of which includes a two-digit number with a leading zero formatted as text and the other one includes an explanation. On the other side I have another empty cell. I want the explanation text to be displayed in that empty cell but the cell should have the two-digit number that's formatted as text as its value internally. I got it to work with a number as the value, but not with the number that's formatted as text.

I've tried the `.Text` tag but it always throws a syntax error. My suspicion is that that's because of the `.NumberFormat` tag and how it's formatted. [Disclaimer: I didn't write this code myself but I have to fix it.]

```
Sub UserDefinedFormatting()

' Delete old output:

Range("G6:G500").ClearContents
Range("G6:G500").NumberFormat = "Text"

' Loop for new output:

For n = 5 To 200

    If Cells(n, 3).Value <> 0 Then

    Value_actual = Cells(n, 3).Value
    Value_shown = Cells(n, 4).Value

    Cells(n, 7).Value = Value_shown
    Cells(n, 7).NumberFormat = "[=" & Value_actual & "]""" & Value_shown & """;General"
    Cells(n, 7).Value = Value_actual

    End If

Next n

End Sub
```

Desired outcome:

```
| I1 |  I2  |      Output     |
| 05 | Test | Test[Value: 05] |
```

Actual outcome:

```
| I1 |  I2  |     Output     |
| 05 | Test | Test[Value: 5] |
```

Somehow it always takes away the leading zero which is essential.

Comment: Format it to 2 digits then: `Format$(Value_shown, "00")`

Comment: That doesn't do anything for me apparently. Maybe I got the syntax wrong?
`Value_actual = Format$(Value_actual, "00")`